# wxPython PopUp notifications

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

We are building an app where in there will be a need to display the updates/notification (ex : like status updates/wall posts on FB). These needs to be displyed at the lower right corner of the window(like any other notifications). So was trying on some alternatives to best display the updates. Some option explored are PopupWindow (which was not that great for status update) and dialog (seems ok). Are there any other good options for this and is there any pre-defined end corners position constants? Plz suggest.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, you can check out [ToasterBox](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/main/ToasterBox.html) - MSN style popups, which should be perfect for your case. (And yes, it is cross platform)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the source code for my RSS notifier application. Example screenshot shown below. Yes, this is implemented with wxPython.

http://www.feednotifier.com/

[image]

The modules to look at are `popups.py` and `theme_default.py`. It's not really written to be a drop-in module, but you can get ideas from it.

Comment: Wow, that is really nice. I would never say this is possible with wxPython

Comment: Woa, thank you for your feednotifier. I use that daily! Love it! Even love it more to know that it is built with WxPython. Will defintely check at the source code

Answer (score 0):

I second the ToasterBox suggestion. You can also create your own Dialog though and position it by grabbing the screen resolution and the size of the dialog and setting its position. I've done the latter for a custom popup. On Macs, you can access Growl through a Python API that's mentioned on their website.