# Python(Linux) send notification to Pc(Windows)

Tags: python, linux, windows, notifications

I've been working on a program in Python, that allows people to interact with the machine via Whatsapp. Now I want to be able to see whenever people send a message in the form of a small pop-up on my windows pc.

What I'm looking for now, is a way to send a message from my Linux machine to my Windows pc. For example I would like to have a line of code in my script, that when ran, the windows pc would receive a notification. I'm sure there are programs out there, but I couldn't find it after an hour of searching.

TL DR; Send a message via a Python script to a windows machine as a notification (in the bottom right)

I would love to hear your ideas!

Rick

Comment: 1: Create a scket 2: Create a pywin32 hook to system32.dll and send a notification. It's not a two-liner or even a three-liner. There's a bunch of code in order to tell Windows to do what you want to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows

Comment: I love wxPython http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755963/wxpython-popup-notifications
http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.toasterbox.ToasterBox.html